# Positioning text slightly more to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place the text a little bit more to right. Tried much of position codes already, but the CSS doesn't read the code, I think.

- Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/6f9cc34d8ed6d33fde401b6317be3a3e

```
.portal .icons a {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    top: 0px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(215, 213, 216, 0.4);
    font-family: ZCOOL QingKe HuangYou;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(215, 213, 216, 0.4);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the Minimal HTML code to reproduce exact problem that you are facing?

Comment: Have you tried margin-left property?

Comment: Either `margin-left` or `left` properties (since you've already set `position: relative;` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

since you added `postition:relative` you should add `left: value_of_how_much_you_wnt_to_push_it_to_the_right`

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
.portal .icons a {
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 15px;
top: 0px;
//add this
left : 100% ; 
transition: all 0.5s ease;
text-decoration: none;
color: rgba(215, 213, 216, 0.4);
font-family: ZCOOL QingKe HuangYou;
font-size: 40px;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(215, 213, 216, 0.4);
```

}

Comment: Thanks it's fixed! <3